# Why does winforms designer doesn't show UI in case of shared resources XDocument load XML?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2017

At the beginning I try to explain it in one sentence. I have a solution with multiple programs and one is only a project to provide a resource.xml for "global settings".

the blue one is my winforms.

[image: solution]

shared resources providing resource.xml

[image: shared resources]

Handler.cs loads the xml, gets the desired setting by name. I tried different ways to load the local resource.xml

[image: handler]

```
    public static XElement GetXElement(string name)
    {
        _cnt++;
        //  Option 1
        //_xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"\resources.xml");

        //  Option 2
        string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
        //MessageBox.Show(appPath);
        _xDoc = XDocument.Load(appPath + "\\resources.xml");

        try
        {
            IEnumerable<XElement> ienuXel = from resource in _xDoc.Descendants("resource")
                                            where resource.Attribute("name").Value.Equals(name)
                                            select resource;
            return ienuXel.Single();
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("SharedResources.Handler: " + "\n\n" + ex.Message, "InvalidOperationException", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }

        XElement xEL = new XElement("null");
        return xEL;
    }
```

each other project has the "shared resource"-project as a reference.

[image: resource]

Since I added GetXElement() to a constructor...

[image: constructor]

```
string _ACMXMLPath = SharedResources.Handler.GetXElement("strACMXMLPath").Value;
string _modifiedXMLpath = SharedResources.Handler.GetXElement("strmodifiedXMLpath").Value;
```

...the winforms designer doesn't laod anymore

[image: winforms designer]

By the way, the resource.xml has the property "Copy to Output Directory"= **Copy always** set.

I guess, it has nothing to do with that path **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE**, because there is no DLL and no PDB of my project/solution.

Comment: You could specify the build action of the XML as "Embedded Resource" and access it using [GetMainfestResourceStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcestream?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: Where do you want the XML file to be located?  When you run from VS it is the bin folder where the c# executable is located.  Try right click the XML file and select properties.  The select the Copy option.

Comment: @prototype0815, is any update?

Comment: Load xml in the Form.Load event instead of the constructor. This will save you from problems with the form designer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, I find that the path you access the xml file is not correct when you use it in another project.

You can refer to the following code to access the xml file path correctly.

```
 public class Handler
    {
        public static XElement GetXElement(string name)
        {
            Type t = typeof(Handler);
            //  get solution path
            string solutionPath =Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.Parent.FullName;
            string finalpath = Path.Combine(solutionPath,t.Namespace,"example.xml");
            var _xDoc = XDocument.Load(finalpath);

            try
            {
                IEnumerable<XElement> ienuXel = from resource in _xDoc.Descendants("resource")
                                                where resource.Attribute("name").Value.Equals(name)
                                                select resource;
                return ienuXel.Single();
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("SharedResources.Handler: " + "\n\n" + ex.Message, "InvalidOperationException", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }

            XElement xEL = new XElement("null");
            return xEL;
        }
    }
```

I make a test in my another winform app.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string result = Handler.GetXElement("test1").Value;
            MessageBox.Show(result);
        }
```

Xml file and tested result:

[image]